# Manipulating scanned pdf files php

Tags: php, pdf-generation

I have some pdf files on my webserver, I want to attach a signature of my website on every page of those files and save them as it is. Those files are scanned and not purely text. I want to make a program which read those files and adds a signature to them. I tried using fpdf and fpdi files but when modifying scanned pages its showing "FPDF error: Unable to find object (8, 0) at expected location" error. My application is not based on zend so I don't want to use zend_pdf for this, I tried many other options, am using shared hosting so am not able to install new extensions of php. Is there any library or something which can do it for me, or if I could do this with pure php.

Comment: By "signature", do you mean watermark?

Comment: no, just name of my website on the top of the page.

Comment: Can you write your code? Perhaps there is an error in your FPDI Code.